# How to add in-line elements so they fill available horizontal space?

Tags: css

My goal is to have items fill the whole width of the parent.
If this is static, I could use `width:%` like `width:33%` for 3 items. The
problem is that number of items will change

```css
#container {
  background-color:red;
}
.item {
  background-color:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <!-- here new items will be added -->
</div>
```

Comment: you should investigate flexbox

Comment: I did with no success. I was closed: I had small content with big spaces fitting the flex container

Comment: @yarek I've added a couple of different methods than flexbox (if you're interested to support older browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using flexbox. You can add more elements on HTML without changing the CSS:

```css
#container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
.item {
  border:1px dashed red;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done in several ways: `Flexbox`, `quantity queries` and `display: table`. I would recommend anyway to use the first approach, unless you need to support `IE<10`

---

## 1. Flexbox

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQEmEL)

**Markup**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <!-- here new items will be added -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container > div {
  flex: 1; 
}
```

Doing so all the inner elements will take always the same space equally distributed.

---

## 2. Quantity queries

Another option is to float elements and use [quantity queries](https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) if you have a limited number of inner elements, e.g.

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpwqVR)

**Markup**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container > div:nth-last-child(5):first-child,
#container > div:nth-last-child(5):first-child ~ div {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

Of course this approach requires to style in CSS every possible amount of inner div that may appear inside the container and requires also some float clearing on the parent container. It's less mantainable but it's worth mentioning as well.

---

## 3. display: table;

Finally, this last example take advantage of `display: table` and `table-cell`

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQrRWz)

Here the style is simply

```
#container { 
   display: table; 
   width: 100%; 
}

.item { 
   display: table-cell; 
}
```